# Connect to Lotus NSF files via MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, lotus

I have a collection of some rather large .NSF lotus database files (around 20 GB) which i should extract the data from.

Unfortunately i have no Access to Domino server so i cannot connect to them via linked server in MSSQL.

Is there an way to connect to those NSF files via MSSQL (linked server or other alternatives) where i could write queries and extract the data from those NSF files ?

I have already tried to extract the data to .SQL files but they are cumbersome and immpossible to import to MSSQL.

Comment: Do you have a Notes- Client? Do you have a Domino Designer Client? If yes: Then you can use LotusScript to extract the data. MSSQL Access is only possible with a special SQL Driver for Domino, but this needs a running Domino Server. Without Notes Client or Domino Server there is no way to access the data... But this question is way to broad for this platform...

Comment: Ye i have Notus Client installed and i can open the files.  I do not have Domino Server or access to it. How would igo about extracting the data using LotusScript?

Comment: Open database with `Set db = New NotesDatabase( "", "PathToYourDatabase.nsf" )`, get document collection of all documents with `Set dc = db.AllDocuments` or subset of documents with `Set dc = db.Search( "Your Formula Query to get the documents you want", Nothing, 0)`. Then run through with `Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument While not doc is Nothing and Set doc = dc.GetNextDocument(doc)` and finally do whatever you want with the items in the document that you get via `doc.GetitemValue( "NameOfItem" )`. That is basically the structure....

Comment: You can write the data to csv files or pump it to a relational database using the appropriate classes and an installed ODBC driver, you can create Excel- Files with the data, extract attachments, etc. etc. But all of that needs some solid knowledge of LotusScript Programming and structures within NSF- Databases...